# Conditional expectation under operations

Tags: conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, expected-value, invariance

I am a bit confused about how the conditional expectation works under operations. I've seen steps such as

$(E[\theta | X])^2 = E[\theta^2 | x]$

Done in proofs without much explanation. My question is, under what conditions is

$h(E[\theta | X]) = E[h(\theta) | X]$

And if you could add an intuitive explanation to it that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that the conditional variance of $\theta$ given $X$ is defined as 
$$Var(\theta|X)=E[\theta^2 | X] - E[\theta | X]^2$$
So $E[\theta^2 | X]=E[\theta|X]^2$ would imply, that the distribution of $\theta$ given $X=x$ will have $0$ variance for all values of $x$, implying that $P(\theta = C_x |\: X=x) = 1$, where $C_x=E[\theta | X=x]\:$. Now suppose that $X$ is a continous random variable with density $f_X$, then
$$P(\theta = E[\theta | X]) = \int_\mathbb{R} P(\theta = E[\theta | X]|X=x)f_X(x)dx =\int_\mathbb{R}f_X(x)dx = 1 $$
(a similar argument holds when $X$ is discrete) Which means that the identity $E[\theta^2 | X]=E[\theta|X]^2$ can only hold, when $\theta$ is almost surely a function of $X$. Writing $\theta = f(X)$ we always have that
$$E[f(X) | X] = f(X)$$
for any function $f$, and therefore
$$E[h(f(X)) | X] = h(f(X)) = h(E[f(X)|X])$$
for all functions $h$. There might be other cases where $E[h(\theta) | X]=h(E[\theta | X])$, but as others have mentioned, this is rarely the case. An important case however, is when $h$ is a linear function, since conditional expectation is linear.

Answer (score 3):

This question does not actually have anything to do with the conditional expectation; you can ask exactly the same question without conditioning on $X$.

The equality is just as incorrect as "$(E[\theta])^2 = E[\theta^2]$." (Unless there are specific additional assumptions in the context where you saw this occur, for instance if $\theta$ is constant/non-random.)

In general, it may be an approximation. For instance, if $h$ has a Taylor series approximation
$$h(\theta) \approx h(E[\theta]) + h'(E[\theta])(\theta - E[\theta])$$
then
$$E[h(\theta)] \approx h(E[\theta]) + h'(E[\theta]) E[\theta - E[\theta]].$$
But again, this (even with the extra term on the right-hand side) is still an approximation, not an equality.

Answer (score 0):

$(\mathbb{E}[\theta | X])^2 \neq \mathbb{E}[\theta^2 | X]$ unless you tell me more about $\theta|X$, for example it is a constant.

$h(\mathbb{E}[\theta | X]) = \mathbb{E}[h(\theta) | X] \iff h(\mathbb{E}[\theta|X]) = \mathbb{E}[h(\theta|X)] $, which is relatively rare.